# Mongoose object does not contain methods

Tags: typescript, mongoose

This is my model

```js
export interface IUser {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    cart: {
        items: { productId: Types.ObjectId; quantity: number }[];
    };
}

interface IUserMethods {
    addToCart(product: HydratedDocument<IProduct>): void;
}

type UserModel = Model<IUser, {}, IUserMethods>;

const userSchema = new Schema<IUser, UserModel, IUserMethods>({
    name: { ... },
    email: { ... },
    cart: { ... },
});

userSchema.methods.addToCart = function (
    this: HydratedDocument<IUser>,
    product: HydratedDocument<IProduct>
) {
    // Do something
    return this.save();
};

const userModel = model<IUser>("User", userSchema);
```

I am trying to use a User object, but it does not contain the addToCart method.
Also, how do I type a User object?

PS: I am trying to do this with the recommended way from the mongoose docs.

Answer (score 0):

Add the methods interface to the `HydratedDocument`, like this:

```
HydratedDocument<IUser, IUserMethods>
```

In my code I re-export this type as `HydratedUser` so I don't need to repeat the bounds everywhere:

```
export type HydratedUser = HydratedDocument<IUser, IUserMethods>;
```

I can't find this clearly documented anywhere, but I figured out looking at the d.ts file that it's expecting the "methods and overrides" interface as the second type parameter:

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/5b62093cc9bcda8842e1be20ed33652547ef60fb/types/index.d.ts#L132

```
export type HydratedDocument<DocType, TMethodsAndOverrides = {}, TVirtuals = {}> = ...
```